# VsCode split terminal trouble

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I entered the split terminal I have got this trouble:"The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) "/mnt/c/Users/..." does not exist." I controlled this path and I saw it existed. How can I solve this problem?
I tried to solve this problem by VsCode trouble shooting. But I have not solved it.

Comment: what shell is this? a wsl one?

Comment: your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77250323/unable-to-split-wsl-terminal-in-windows-vscode