# Unable to split WSL terminal in windows VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I attempted to split the terminal in VSCode, which resulted in the issue described below.

The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) `"/mnt/c/{PATH}/my_projects/chat-app"` does not exist.

The default terminal I am trying to use is WSL Ubuntu

How can fix this to use WSL terminal in VSCode as default terminal and enable splitting?
[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMEpi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change Terminal > Integrated: Split Cwd to "initial":

[image]

But if you want to split terminal to WSL, you must specified terminal.
"Split Terminal" and then choose WSL.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks. Fixed my issue. But why is this happening? what is the root cause?